# Django : cannot find the static files

Tags: django, static, django-staticfiles

In my Django project, the settings are the following ones:
A settings folder, including a `base.py` and a `production.py` files.
The base folder defines a path taking into account this tree:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(__file__, os.pardir))))
```

And the static is defined as such:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

When I launch `collectstatic` the static folder is mounted at the root of the project, as planned.
However, the static files are not found neither by the html pages, although configured as seach:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style_sheet.css' %}">
    <title>{% block title %}Advocacy Project{% endblock %}</title>

</head>
```

and when I check with `findstatic`, it looks like it does not look into the right folders:

```
python manage.py findstatic style_sheet.css --settings my_project.settings.production --verbosity 2
No matching file found for 'style_sheet.css'.

Looking in the following locations:
  /Users/my_name/Documents/my_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static
```

My question is: How could I make Django check in the right folders ?

Comment: What is `BASE_DIR` value, what is the actual file list/structure of `BASE_DIR/static`?

Comment: I have just added this in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if debug = False or True in your setting. Django will not host your static files in Debug = False mode. You have to use something like whitenoise to host you static files in production.

Comment: Solution seems great, however it created "bad request" errors in DEBUG=False and half of the views are discarded. Do you have a clue ?

Comment: Great. It works. I just need to add a layer for different settings.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks ASFAW AYALKIBET support here is a detailed process to install Whitenoise on Django with multiple settings.

1. Install Whitenoise `pip install Whitenoise`
2. Create `settings` folder in the project folder.
3. Add `base.py` and `production.py` along with the `__init__.py` file in this folder.
4. in `production.py` add

```
DEBUG = False
```

5. In the settings, amend `BASE_DIR` as such :
   `BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent`
   insert `'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic'`in `INSTALLED_APPS` and `'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware'` in `MIDDLEWARE`,(cf whitenoise official doc).
6. Again in the settings, add `STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'`
7. In wsgi.py amend the settings path:
   `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_project.settings.production')`
8. then you can collect the static files using:
   `python manage.py collectstatic --settings settings.my_project.production`
9. Launch the servers:
   `gunicorn my_project.wsgi` to check the production mode
   `python manage.py runserver --settings settings.my_project.base` to use the debug mode.